"How to fix '415 Unsupported Media Type' error when uploading a post with an image using Spring Boot backend and React frontend?"
I have implemented a backend method in Spring Boot to allow users to create posts with or without an image. The backend method is as follows:
@PostMapping(value = "/posts/add", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
@ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "Please check the payload or token")
@ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Post added with image")
@Operation(summary = "Add a new Post with optional image")
@SecurityRequirement(name = "studyeasy-demo-api")
public ResponseEntity<?> addPostWithImage(
        @Parameter(content = @Content(mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)) @RequestPart("caption") PostPayloadDTO postPayloadDTO,
        @RequestPart(value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile file,
        @RequestParam("postTypeName") String postTypeName,
        Authentication authentication) {
    try {
        // Xác thực email và người dùng
        String email = authentication.getName();
        Optional<Account> optionalAccount = accountService.findByEmail(email);
        Users users = optionalAccount.get().getUser();
        Post post = new Post();
        post.setUser(users);
        post.setCaption(postPayloadDTO.getCaption());
        PostType postType = postTypeService.getPostTypeByName(postTypeName);
        post.setPostType(postType);
        postService.save(post);
        
        if (file != null && !file.isEmpty()) {
            String contentType = file.getContentType();
            if (contentType.equals("image/png") || contentType.equals("image/jpg") || contentType.equals("image/jpeg")) {
                String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
                String generatedString = RandomStringUtils.random(10, true, true);
                String finalImageName = generatedString + fileName;
                String absoluteFileLocation = AppUtil.get_photo_upload_path(finalImageName, PHOTOS_FOLDER_NAME, post.getPostId());

                Path path = Paths.get(absoluteFileLocation);
                Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), path, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

                post.setPostImgURL(absoluteFileLocation); // Lưu đường dẫn ảnh vào post
                
                // Tạo đối tượng Photo và lưu thông tin file vào cơ sở dữ liệu
                Photo photo = new Photo();
                photo.setName(fileName); // Lưu tên gốc của file
                photo.setFileName(finalImageName); // Lưu tên file sau khi thêm chuỗi ngẫu nhiên
                photo.setOriginalFileName(fileName); // Lưu tên file gốc
                photo.setPost(post); // Liên kết ảnh với album
                photoService.save(photo); // Lưu ảnh vào database
            } else {
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
                        .body("Unsupported file format. Please use PNG, JPG, or JPEG.");
            }
        }

        List<PhotoDTO> photos = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Photo photo : photoService.findByPostId(post.getPostId())) {
            String link = "/posts/" + post.getPostId() + "/photos/" + photo.getId() + "/download-photo";
            photos.add(new PhotoDTO(photo.getId(), photo.getName(), photo.getDescription(), photo.getFileName(), link));
        }

        // Lưu post vào database
        post = postService.save(post);
        PostViewDTO postViewDTO = new PostViewDTO(post.getPostId(), post.getUser().getProfileImage(), post.getCaption(), post.getUser().getUserName(), photos);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(postViewDTO);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.debug("Error adding post with image: " + e.getMessage());
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(null);
    }
}

I have tested the backend API using Postman, and it works as expected—both with and without an image.
However, when I try to call the same API from the frontend (React), I get the following error in the browser console:
POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/posts/add 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

And in the backend logs, I see:
[org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content-Type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported]

Here's the relevant code from my React frontend:
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { fetchPostFileUploadWithAuth } from 'client/client';

const Share = () => {
  const [file, setFile] = useState(null);
  const [description, setDescription] = useState('');
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleShare = async () => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('caption', description);
    formData.append('postTypeName', 'normal');

    if (file) {
      formData.append('file', file);
    }

    try {
      await fetchPostFileUploadWithAuth('/posts/add', formData);
      setDescription('');
      setFile(null);
      navigate('/');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to create post:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="share">
      {/* JSX for file input, caption, etc. */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Share;

The issue occurs when I try to upload anything (with or without the image). The backend method is correctly set to consume multipart/form-data, and I am using FormData in the frontend to send the request.
I am using the following function for the API call:
const fetchPostFileUploadWithAuth = async (uri, formData) => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  const url = `${API_version}${uri}`;
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(url, formData, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    });
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle errors if the request fails
    console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
  }
};


Well, this error is familiar, because it gave me sleepless nights. 415 Unsupported Media Type. I think this means that the content type of the request doesn't match what spring-boot expects. Since you've confirmed that your BE API works, I suspect tat the issue is in how React is making the request. Just making educated guesses here. Here are a few things you can try:

Check that the field names in your FormData match the param names in your controller. FormData (caption, file, and postTypeName)

Please check your axios version. I put this here because some versions of axios have known issues with FormData

Remove Content-Type header I think because axios automatically sets the Content-Type header to multipart/form-data with a boundary, which is essential for FormData to work properly. Manually setting Content-Type can interfere with this. So Try removing 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' from the headers like this:


const response = await axios.post(url, formData, {
  headers: {
    "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`,
  },
});


If all else fails, you can use fetch API directly. So instead use axios.post to utilize the native fetch API to send the request. Here's what the code might look it:


const handleShare = async () => {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('caption', description);
  formData.append('postTypeName', 'normal');

  if (file) {
    formData.append('file', file);
  }

  try {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    const url = `<span class="math-inline">\{API\_version\}</span>{uri}`;
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
      headers: {
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`Network   
 response was not ok:   
 ${response.status}`);
    }

    setDescription('');
    setFile(null);
    navigate('/');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Failed to create post:', error);
  }
};


You can set postTypeName in FormData instead of RequestParam: Since you've currently added postTypeName as a RequestParam, it might not work as expected in a FormData object. Instead, please ensure that postTypeName is added as a RequestPart parameter in your controller. Do you understand?

I would also improve your addPostWithImage endpoint like this.
@PostMapping(value = "/posts/add", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
@ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "Please check the payload or token")
@ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Post added with image")
@Operation(summary = "Add a new Post with optional image")
@SecurityRequirement(name = "studyeasy-demo-api")
public ResponseEntity<?> addPostWithImage(
        @Parameter(content = @Content(mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)) @RequestPart("caption") PostPayloadDTO postPayloadDTO,
        @RequestPart(value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile file,
        @RequestPart("postTypeName") String postTypeName, // I changed this from RequestParam to RequestPart
        Authentication authentication) {
    ...
}

These are some of the issues I could immediately spot with your code. Try and change them and please let me know.

+1 for removing the content type header. Please check the warning here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest_API/Using_FormData_Objects#sending_files_using_a_formdata_object

Yes, When you set the Content-Type manually to multipart/form-data in the headers, it overrides the browser's automatic handling of FormData, which includes the boundary parameter that’s essential for the backend to parse multipart data correctly. That's why I removed the Content-Type header from the axios request.
  headers: {
    "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`,
  },
});

